# Is there any historical basis for the red/white color scheme of the Assassins?

Tags: crusades, clothing, assassination, game

I recently saw a documentary about the Crusades, and during the scene in which Saladin is almost assassinated by the [historical order of Assassins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassins), they are portrayed as wearing plain white clothes with red sashes.  This is, of course, quite similar to the clothing portrayed in the *[Assassin's Creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed)* video game series, especially the Crusades-era character, [Altaïr Ibn-La'Ahad](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120907164457/assassinscreed/images/e/e9/AC1_Altair_Render_Concept.png).

Is there any historical basis for this clothing pattern or color scheme?  It seems odd to have both a video game (which is obviously fictional but which famously includes numerous true-history elements) and a genuine documentary about the period share such a specific trait if it wasn't grounded in truth, but then it could also be an in-joke or a playful nod from the costuming department of the documentary.

I can't find anything in my research, but that's mostly because I just end up finding *Assassin's Creed*-related images and information, not historical.  (This is the problem when a historical order has such a generic name.)

Does anyone know if the red/white color scheme has any historical basis from the actual [assassins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassins) of Persia and Syria?  Or was that purely a fabrication for the video game series?

Answer (score 5):

The preferred tactic of the so-called Assassins (or, as they called themselves, the Fida’iyyun) was to come up close to a public figure and kill him with a sword. It is difficult to see how they could have could have got so near to their victims, unchallenged, if they were wearing a distinctive uniform. The whole point was that they blended in to the crowd.

Comment: Although Ḥashshāshīns were a paramilitary/religious organisation. They may have had a "dress uniform" when not in action.

Comment: "may have" is not an answer.

Comment: But "may have" *is* an adequate response to "It is difficult to see how..."  Good answer, either way.  I would be curious to know if anyone else has other information, perhaps relevant to the robes worn by initiates during training or by masters during ceremonies, etc.

Comment: @fdb Yes, it's a comment.